# How to use @AttributeOverrides when used method access to property?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an Embeddable class with **method access** to properties. It works fine until there two or more inclusions in one other class where I have to use @AttributeOverrides.

At this case I receive the following error from Hibernate:

> Repeated column in mapping for entity: ... column: grn_date (should be
>   mapped with insert="false" update="false")

It seems Hibernate for some reasons doesn't understand method access. If I use common property-access all works fine, but I need current one to get Calendar date from XMLGregorianCalendar field.

**Embeddable class:**

```
@Embeddable
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "...")
public class GrnType {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "...")
    @Transient
    protected String grn;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "...", required = true)
    @Transient
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar dateOfEntry;

    @Transient
    private Calendar calendarDate;


    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    @Column(name = "grn")
    public String getGrn() {
        return grn;
    }

    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    @Column(name = "grn_date")
    private Calendar getCalendarDate() {
         if(dateOfEntry!=null) {
             return new GregorianCalendar(dateOfEntry.getYear(), dateOfEntry.getMonth(), dateOfEntry.getDay());
         }else {
             return null;
         }
    }

    //   ...setters here

}
```

Class where embedded:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="RealEstateDFl")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {...})
public class GrnEntity {

    //...
    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "grn", column = @Column(name = "grn_main")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "grn_date", column = @Column(name = "grn_date_main"))
    })
    protected GrnType grnType;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "grn", column = @Column(name = "grn_sec")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "grn_date", column = @Column(name = "grn_date_sec"))
    })
    protected GrnType grnTypeSecondary;

    //...
}
```

Could anyone advice how to override attributes properly at this case? Or what might be the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. It was pretty tricky for me.

At the class where embedded it needs to set **not the name of the column but the name of the variable**, in my case it is *calendarDate*.

So here is a working example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="RealEstateDFl")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {...})
public class GrnEntity {

    //...
    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "grn", column = @Column(name = "grn_main")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "calendarDate", column = @Column(name = "grn_date_main"))
    })
    protected GrnType grnType;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "grn", column = @Column(name = "grn_sec")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "calendarDate", column = @Column(name = "grn_date_sec"))
    })
    protected GrnType grnTypeSecondary;

    //...
}
```

Also getters and setters in Embeddable class should exactly match the property names.